# Using Windows OBJ files on OSX

Tags: macos, delphi

The Windows version of my Delphi application uses the ZipForge component. With a couple of changes I was able to compile it for OSX. The catch is that the code links in c obj files that were compiled to obj files for Windows with Delphi XE2. I thought that would never work and crash my application immediately when running on OSX, but that didn't happen. It was able to generate valid zip files on OSX.

```
{$L zlib32\deflate.obj}
function deflateInit_(var strm: TZStreamRec; level: Integer; version: PAnsiChar; 
  recsize: Integer): Integer; external; // this function is in the .obj files
```

I know that on OSX I need to be careful in order to follow the stack alignment rules. But I don't know enough about obj files and what happens when these are linked in. Was I just lucky that OSX didn't find out that stack alignment or other things might have been wrong, or does Delphi XE5 for OSX make sure that the stack alignment will be correct even inside the code of the obj files when linking it into the application?

Comment: This is dubious at best. Not to mention pointless. Delphi ships with zlib. You can compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now checked this with the Delphi debugger. When linking in the Windows .obj files, the stack alignment will be wrong as soon as a function that is not a leaf function is called. There might be a few cases where this doesn't matter, but most of the time it will create problems that are not immediately visible.